# This question appeared in a mate's child's homework and it's broken my brain.

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

I could use gaussian elimination if I make some assumptions or does any one have another suggestion?

Comment: It looks like the symbol means you subtract the second number from the first and then subtract two

Comment: Define that symbol $\circ$ as an operator of two inputs such that $a\circ b= a-b-2$.

Comment: that's a bruh moment

Comment: Of course there are infinitely many functions satisfying $f(10,3)=5, f(8,1)=5, f(6,2)=2$ so technically $f(9,2)$ does not have a unique value. However, assuming the child hasn't learnt multiplication or division yet, you basically have $10 ± 3 ± a = 5$ and so on for the other equations, so there aren't too many possibilities.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Andrew Chin's answer definitely works. Define $x\boxdot y$ by 
$$x \boxdot y = x - y - 2,$$
and it fits the data given.

Answer (score 0):

Say the first number is *x*, the second is *y*, and the answer is *A*.

I believe the formula is *A* = *x*-(2+*y*).

Another that works is *A* = *x*-*y*-2

According to this logic:

a) 9 ● 2=5

b) ● = -2-

I hope that answers your question.

Comment: Your two formulas are the same.

Comment: I know they're the same, I was just giving two examples.